# Can All 4-D column matrices be given as tensor product of 2-D column matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

I am familiar with entanglement concept. But it feels bit weird to me that all possibilities of a system in a $4$-dimensional  vector  space cannot be given as tensor  product of  two $2$-dimensional vector spaces for eg. 
$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  \\
0  \\
0  \\
1  \end{array} \right)$$ 
can't be given as tensor product of two $2$x$1$ matrices.As I see two $2$x$1$ matrices are independent and still tensor product of them is not spanning the entire $4$x$1$ vector space.
Am I missing something or making a blunder ? If I am correct then why in classical theory every 4 bit of information can be given as two $2$ bits of information but the same is not true for qubits in quantum mechanics ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Hilbert spaces themselves, we indeed find the puzzling equality
$$\mathbb{C}^2\times\mathbb{C}^2 = \mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2 = \mathbb{C}^4$$
so the tensor product of the qubit spaces is equal to the pairs of non-entangled states. **Or so it would seem.**

The superficial equality is wrong in the physical context, because the isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}^2\times\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$ would *not* be given by the map $v\times w = (v,w)\mapsto v\otimes w$, but by a different one. Indeed, the map
$$\mathbb{C}^2\times\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2, (v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2)\mapsto v\otimes w = (v_1w_1,v_1w_2,v_2w_1,v_2w_2) $$
is not an isomorphism, since vectors like $(1,0,0,1)$ do not lie in its image. So, although the spaces of non-entangled and all states are *abstractly* isomorphic, they are not in a way that would indicate all states are entangled.

Passing to the [projective Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space) takes care of that for us (removes the superfical equality), and then we get the [Segre embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) of the non-entangled states into the total space:
$$ S^2 \times S^2 \to P\mathbb{C}^4$$
where $S^2 = P\mathbb{C}^2$ is the well-known [Bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere). This map is *not* bijective, but only a "part" of the larger [Hopf fibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)
$$ S^3\to S^7\to S^4$$ 
that can be used to describe the full two-qubit system. (For details on this Hopf fibration, see [*"Geometry of entangled states, Bloch spheres and Hopf fibrations"*](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108137) by R. Mosseri and R. Dandoloff)

Comment: Are you saying that it happens due to the normalization condition ? could you please explain. Your answer is surely elaborate but being a beginner in quantum computation I am bit confused .

Comment: @sasha: You know that every quantum state is represented by a unit vector. Plainly speaking, I am saying that, although the *full spaces* are equal, not every *unit vector* in $\mathbb{C}^4$ comes from the tensor product of two *unit vectors* in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: If the normalization condition was relaxed still I could not represent the above matrix $A$ as tensor products . Am I correct about that ?

Comment: @sasha: No, taking the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) as the tensor product, we cannot write that $A$ as a simple tensor product.

Comment: I did not read in detail the links, will do so surely. But after your edit I understood. Thanks a lot, it was really helpful.